# Git checkout not making changes

Tags: git, github, version-control

In my android project, I had a master branch, then I made another experimental branch and made around 30 commits in that, now experimental branch was far better than master so I decided to rename master as master-abandoned and the experimental branch as master.
Now git log is giving the history of all commits but code in android studio is not changing it's stuck at some earlier commit.

[In the bottom right side I can see my files(grey color) which should be there in project directory of my latest commits but they are not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRjMu.jpg)

[NotificationUtils is not present (updated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwSc0.jpg)

Also, I've pushed changes in my remote branch, but I cannot see any of these files there too, but when opening the latest commit, files are there.

Comment: Can you show the entire Andorid studio window here? The information for which local branch HEAD point to is necessaty (as the local branch is b2 in the screen shot https://ibb.co/ehsXCo).

Comment: That's not the screenshot I've linked, it's https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRjMu.jpg

Comment: It wasn't implied that that is your screenshot. It's an example of what your screenshot is missing.

Comment: The link is an example. I mean can you also show the bottum line in your screen shot?

Comment: Really sorry for that, updated.

Comment: So didn't you rename master branch yet?

Comment: master (renamed to master-abandoned), experimental(renamed to master) both are then pushed to the remote

Comment: If you already renamed the two branches, then all the commit history (as the arounf 30 commits) will be shown in the current master branch (old experimental branach). And what do you mean "not making changes"?

Comment: Yes, history is there, but files in grey in above images were there in my commit before renaming but now they are not, even after checking out master or any earlier commit, they are just shown in grey in bottom right corner

Comment: @K'aRtiKSharma It only shows the changed file in the log window (as the area inside the red rectangle in my answer). You should chheck files of a commit in the project directory (as the area inside the green rectangle in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files list in the log window is for the changed files by comparing with the pervious commit (parent commit) which were committed in a selected commit.

To get all the files of a commit (including changed and non-changed), you should check in the project directory.

[image]

For the changed files show in the log window:

- The gray files: means the files were deleted in the selected commit (exist in the pervious commit, and delete in the selected commit);
- Not gray files: means the files were modified in the selected commit.

Comment: Thanks, but files in red window (PagerViewAdapeter, ProfileBlogRecyclerAdapter) are not present in the green window nor they are changing on checking out any previous commit.

Comment: The gray files (such as PageViewAdapter.java) means they exist in the pervious commit (the commit message is `Add:Profile post About still needs to be implemented`), but the files were deleted when commited changhes in the selected commit (the commit message is `Change: Branch name Slight issues`).

Comment: So is there a way to revert the changes permanently to the previous commit without making any other branch?

Comment: Yes, you can execute `git reset --hard HEAD~` and `git push -f` in terminal window (on local `master` branch).

Comment: git push -f
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>

Comment: Ahh, It should use the command `git reset --hard HEAD~` instead. Please execute following commands: `git checkout master`, `git reset --hard HEAD~` and `git push -f`.

Comment: @K'aRtiKSharma Do you reset master branch to the pervious commit successful now?